# Dois Formulários trabalhando sobre o mesmo resultset

Tags: html

Como se faz para termos dois formularios trabalhando sobre o mesmo resultset? Tendo como exemplo a pesquisa do youtube (veja abaixo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em Vermelho a pesquisa padrão onde o usuario coloca a pesquisa e clica no botão de envio de formulario (no caso a lupa) e em Verde um outro formulario com os filtros de resultado que aparecem somente após a pesquisa inicial este formulario verde não necessita de click em qualquer tecla submit, o que quero saber é como se faz o segundo formulario (Verde)? como não é necessario um click de submissão, como reaproveita o resultado do formulario em vermelho, como o interligo ao formulario vermelho?

Formulario que fiz:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes usar JavaScript para ter ações quando clicas numa das opções do verde, e assim fazer o submit *automático*.

Comment: mas e quanto ao filtro e sort das informações retornadas do banco?

Comment: tens de criar o filtro conforme as opções selecionadas, ao fazeres o submit *automático* vais enviar os dados escolhidos pelo utilizador, e ai podes montar a tua query de pesquisa.

Comment: Exemplo: `SELECT * FROM tabela1 WHERE tabela1.nome LIKE '%php%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,tabela1.tempo,NOW()) < 60`. Isto seria uma pesquisa com a palavra "php" e na última hora

Comment: Ok, mas eu estaria repetindo a consulta já que foi realizada a consulta inicial pesquisando somente PHP (depois é que esta disponivel o formulario verde para filtro), como eu faria o formulario verde atendendo as questões elencadas?

Comment: Sim, tu fazes a primeira pesquisa só por "php" em seguida ao mostrar o resultado mostras o form verde. E com ajuda do JavaScript, em cada clique que fizeres nesse formulário é feito um submit, como se tivesses clicado num botão. E a cada click fazes uma nova pesquisa com o filtro em que clicaste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Com HTML5**:

Formulário principal:

```
<form id="search_form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search_query" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Complemento do formulário (em outro local da página):

```
<div id="search_filter">
    Upload date:<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="upload_date" value="any" form="search_form" /> Any time<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="upload_date" value="month" form="search_form" /> This month<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="upload_date" value="year" form="search_form" /> This year<br/>
</div>
```

Veja a propriedade `form` das tags `input`, ela indica que aquela tag `input` pertence ao formulário de cima, mesmo que ela não esteja dentro dele.

**Sem HTML5 (Com Javascript)**

Formulário principal:

```
<form id="search_form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search_query" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="upload_date" />
</form>
```

Repare no campo `upload_date` como `hidden`.

Complemento do formulário (em outro local da página):

```
<div id="search_filter">
    Upload date:<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="upload_date" value="any" /> Any time<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="upload_date" value="month" /> This month<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="upload_date" value="year" /> This year<br/>
</div>
```

Código Javascript:

```
$("#search_filter > input[name=upload_date]").change(function() {
    var $update = $("#search_form > input[name=upload_date]"),
        value = $(this).prop("value");
    $update.prop("value",value);
});
```

Sempre que um `radio` dentro da `div#search_filter` é alterado ele atualiza o valor do `upload_date` que está escondido dentro do formulário original. Só é um pouco mais trabalhoso mapear estes eventos dos elementos que estão fora do formulário para os verdadeiros que estão dentro.

Comment: utilizando a solução com HTML5 sempre que o usuario mudar os radio buttons o resultado da query será atualizado? (haverá a submissão do formulario com a nova opção marcada?)